# Calling Drive API for Android on Separate thread returns no data

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using the Drive API v2 for android, and when I execute the following method my app seems to pause or wait, and no data is returned.

```
    public About getAbout() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    FutureTask<About> future = new FutureTask<About>(new Callable<About>() {
        public About call() throws IOException {

            About about = null;
            try {
                about = _driveService.about().get().execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return about;

        }
    });

    About about = future.get();
    return about;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `FutureTask`, but you are never executing it (not on the current thread and not on any other). Then you call `future.get()` which will block until the operation is completed. Since you never actually perform the operation, it will wait forever.

To execute an operation on a background thread you could for example use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html